# Tried to load angular more than once with express 4

Tags: angularjs, express

When I try to load an angular route (and therefore a template) I get this error:

*WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.*

I think there's a problem with routing that's causing an infinite loop but I just can't work out what the issue is.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express(); //Create the Express app

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

module.exports = app;
```

**app.js**

```
angular
  .module('vapescannerApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'theControllers'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.ejs',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.ejs',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .when('/something/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'views/ProductDetails.ejs',
        controller: 'DetailsCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

**www.js**

```
var app = require('../server');

app.get('*', function(req, res){

    res.render("index");

});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

**App Structure**

```
-- bin
   - www.js
-- public
   - app.js
-- server
   -- views
      - productDetails.ejs
      - main.ejs
      - about.ejs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render("index");
```

It's hard to say exactly but this will redirect *every* route to render `index`.  If you have a route that does not match a file in your public directory, express will attempt to render the index file again.  If the index file is including Angular, it's possible that the inclusion is rendered twice.  You can turn off this route or make it more specific for debugging purposes to confirm that all of your resources are being included properly.

Comment: You're right. Added in a route above for the partials and it's working. Thanks for your help.